# Logout PHP Script

Tags: php, logout

This is my script:

```
<?php
  // If the user is logged in, delete the session vars to log them out
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // Delete the session vars by clearing the $_SESSION array
    $_SESSION = array();

    // Delete the session cookie by setting its expiration to an hour ago (3600)
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {      setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600);    }

    // Destroy the session
    session_destroy();
  }

  // Delete the user ID and username cookies by setting their expirations to an hour ago (3600)
  setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 3600);
  setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);

  // Redirect to the home page
  $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . $home_url);
?>
```

I cannot log out once logged in on the site. Do I really need cookie'd logins or can I take that out?

Comment: If you are not accessing the cookies in javascript on the client side, you can just use the PHP session and avoid cookies.

Comment: I haven't used cookie logins before. I just start the session on each page, and on logout destroy the session. That's just me though.

Comment: I like  WreithKassan that Idea better

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try a simpler approach, destroy all session cookies

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to using this method,

```
<?php
//User session in ['user']
if($_SESSION['user_id']){
  session_start();
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  session_write_close();
  setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
  session_regenerate_id(true);
}
?>
```

i recommend you using that method
, why? because that method using `true destroy`,`delete cookie in browser` and `new set ID of session` of session in PHP

Answer (score 0):

"In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that."
see: https://www.php.net/session_destroy
and: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php
"Caution
Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal."
see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php