# Cookie session is not invalidated after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my web application built with codeigniter 2 that has login and logout feature. But i can't invalidate a session cookie ater user logout on the system. What i mean is that when a user is logout he can reuse his or her previous session cookie to get access on dashboard. Which looks like the cookie is only clearead on client browser but still valid on server side.
Here is the my logout function...

```
function logout(){
    $user = new User($this->session->userdata('uid'));
    $user->last_active = (time());
    //$user->last_login = date_convert(time(),true);
    $user->login_status = 0;
    if($user->id) $user->save();

    $log = new UserLogger();
    $log->ulog($this->session->userdata('uid'),'Logout',"User Successfully Logged out of System",0,0,0);
    $this->session->set_userdata('form_token',false);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->SystemCore->clearUserSession();
    $this->index();
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We don’t want to be shown images of code here, all code relevant to your problem ([mre]) belongs directly into your question in text form, and properly formatted.

Comment: thank you.. its my first time asking question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is destroying all session cookies

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) .'/index.php';
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

[Logout PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320524/logout-php-script/21320798#21320798)